# Inverse Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis

I am dealing with an inverse Fourier transform of a sampled complex function, $H(\omega)$. I want to obtain a **real** transformed function $h(t)$, which means that $H(-\omega)=H^{\ast}(\omega)$ has to be fulfilled. In order to have $h(t)$ sampled both for positive and negative times I use following procedure:

```
 h_c = RotateRight[InverseFourier[RotateLeft[Join[Conjugate[Reverse[H]],H], n/2 \[Minus]1], 
 FourierParameters -> {0, 1}], n/2 \[Minus] 1]
```

What bothers me is that $h_c$ is generally complex. Then I simply take only its real part, e.g.

```
 h = Re[h_c]
```

However, I wonder if this approach is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach using `Re[]` is at least questionable and even more important, not necessary. First notice how *Mathematica* performs the Fourier transformation. It stores $\omega=0$ in the first element of the list. The highest frequencies are in the middle.
Doing something like the following results in a real valued transformation

```
t1Lst=Table[i+ I i Sin[2.1 i],{i,0,3,.1}];
tLst=Join[t1Lst, Conjugate[ Reverse[ Drop[t1Lst , 1] ] ] ];
InverseFourier[tLst]
```

This list unfortunately has an odd number of elements, though. Naturally you must assure that the $\omega=0$ value is real. If you want an even number of list elements you must also assure that the high frequency value $\omega_\mathrm{max}$ is real valued.

So a list of type $a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_{n-1},a_n, a_{n-1}^* ,\ldots ,a_1^* $ with $a_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ and   $a_n \in \mathbb{R}$