# Inverse Fourier transform to get real function

Tags: fourier-analysis

I have got a sampled complex function, $H(\omega)$ and know that its inverse Fourier transform has to be **real** function $h(t)$, which means that $H(-\omega)=H^{\ast}(\omega)$ has to be fulfilled. If we used properties I mentioned, we would get $h(t)=\frac{2}{\pi}
\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{Re}\lbrace H(\omega)\mathrm{exp}(-\mathrm{i}\omega t)\rbrace\,\mathrm{d}\omega$ for "continuous" IFT. Is it somehow possible to implement this in discrete IFT used in *Mathematica*? I want to obtain $h(t)$ both for positive and negative times.

Comment: Duplicate of this http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/67670/1783